# Restricted scopes in an Apps Script library without the client needing the same scopes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I'm writing a Google Apps Script library that's functionally a mail merge with a few bells & whistles. The goal is that a client could add this library and a small amount of boilerplate code to a Google spreadsheet, and it would "just work".

This has generally been working just fine, but I'm now trying to add the ability to add the user's signature to the end of the emails generated. Here's the line in the library:

```
const signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;
```

Once that line is added, however, I opened a whole can of worms. As far as I understand it, that code accesses a "restricted scope" in Gmail, and so I had to upgrade from a "default project" to a "standard project" in GCP, which I believe I did successfully (though the app is not yet verified.) My library itself works just fine now and adds the signature. Hooray!

However, when I test the library from a client spreadsheet, I now get this error:
`Exception: Service Gmail API has not been enabled for your Apps Script-managed Cloud Platform project. If you recently turned on this advanced Google service, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.`

If I comment out the signature line, everything runs fine in the client once again.

So my question is: can you use restricted scopes in a Apps Script library without the client needing the same scopes?

(Perhaps I'm simply thinking about this incorrectly; while I'm not new to Apps Script, I've not needed to use GCP before.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone using your library must get their addon approved from Google since it uses a restricted scope. It is a time-taking process and you'd have to a good fee to the security assessor approved by Google for evaluating your source.

However, if your client builds an add-on using your library for their own use or for an internal addon (that is visible only in their own domain), the restrictions may not apply.